# How to stream a string list and sort it based on a number in each item

Tags: java, string, list, java-stream

I have a list of events. Each item has the following elements player name, time of event, event name, separated by space. The player name can be either be first name or both first name and last name.
Example [ "Mark 45 G", "Rob 4 Y", "Jude Tom 6 R"]. I want to sort the list based on the chronological order of the event time. So the output will be  ["Rob 4 Y", "Jude Tom 6 R", "Mark 45 G"]
I have created a Event POJO class with properties String player,int time,String event, with getters and setters. What I want is something like this

```
List<String> events=  Arrays.asList( new String[]  {"Mark 45 G", "Rob 4 Y", "Jude Tom 6 R" });
List<Event> orderedEvents = events.stream()
               .map(a -> new Event(a[0], a[1], a[2]))
               .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Event::getTime))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I do not know how to get the string to the three fields. Since the time can come on second or third position (if the last name is also given)

Comment: Split by space, if the result contains 3 elements you have one name, if the result contains 4 elements you have first and last name.

Comment: Seriously, create a POJO for the `String` values and then stream that one...

Comment: How would you interpret `Jude Tom 6 R` into 3 strings and do state why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost done. You just have to correctly map the `String` event to the `Event` class.
Solution:

```java
class Event {
    private String playerName; 
    private int time;
    private String name;

    public Event(String eventString) {
        String[] params = eventString.split(" ");
        int i = 0;
        this.playerName = params[i++];
        if (params.length == 4) {
            this.playerName += " " + params[i++];
        }
        this.time = Integer.valueOf(params[i++]);
        this.name = params[i];
    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Event{");
        sb.append("playerName='").append(playerName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", time=").append(time);
        sb.append(", name='").append(name).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    List<String> events = Arrays.asList("Mark 45 G", "Rob 4 Y", "Jude Tom 6 R");
    List<Event> orderedEvents = events.stream()
            .map(eventString -> new Event(eventString))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Event::getTime))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(orderedEvents);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to customize how to spliting a string.

```java
      String[] str = { "Mark 45 G", "Rob 4 Y", "Jude Tom 6 R"
      };
      Function<String, String[]> split = a ->
      {
         String[] p = a.split("\\s+");
         if (p.length > 3) {
            p = new String[] { p[0] + " " + p[1], p[2], p[3]
            };
         }
         return p;
      };

      for (String s : str) {
         String[] parts = split.apply(s);
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
      }
```